# how to get a userIds or users associated with particular assets category

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

If I create a new category it will store in AssestCategory table.At the same time entry should be in AssestEntry table also.For mapping between these two tables we have AssestEntries_AssestCategories table.How to achieve above thing by programmatically because for mapping table I didn't get any API.by these tables shall I get userIds associated with particular category. Or let me know is there any other way.

Answer (score 0):

A new entry stored in AssetCategory when a category is created for a topic in site.
For example, Create a category named "Test Category" in site. You will see an entry in AssetCategory table. But there will not be any entry get stored to AssetEntries_AssetCategories table.

When the category is associated with some data item, then its association is stored in AssetEntries_AssetCategories table.
For example, When you create a bookmark with "Test Category" selected, then a new entry stores in AssetEntries_AssetCategories table.

entryId in AssetEntries_AssetCategories represents the corresponding entry for AssetEntry table.

In liferay Asset framework, liferay-ui:asset-categories-selector tag can be used to provide Asset category selection.

Please refer below links for details of liferay asset framework and to implement the same for a custom resource.

https://www.liferay.com/en_GB/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/asset-framework-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-06-en

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/learning-paths/-/knowledge_base/6-2/enabling-assets-at-the-service-layer